# FFMPEG find if MOV videos is h.264

Tags: php, ffmpeg, codec, encoder, mencoder

How can we find out in PHP if a MOV or MP4 video is encoded with h.264. I have both mencoder and FFMPEG installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
exec( "ffmpeg -i {$strFilePath}", $return, $status );
if( $status == 0 ) {
    // I do ot have ffmpeg installed on this machine so I can't write your check
    // But a simple str_pos() will tell you if the h264 codec string is there.
    $isH264 = str_pos($return, /*the codec string here*/ ) !== false;
}
?>
```